# if else jQuery not working with ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have below code :

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'upload.php',  //Server script to process data
    type: 'POST',
    xhr: function() {  // Custom XMLHttpRequest
        var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
        if(myXhr.upload){ // Check if upload property exists
            myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress',progressHandlingFunction, false); // For handling the progress of the upload
        }
        return myXhr;
    },
    //Ajax events
    beforeSend: function(e) { $('#progress').css('display', 'block'); },
    success: function(e) {
        if (e != "bad" || e != "No") {
            alert('File Upload Success!');
            $('#imgsrc').attr("src", e);
            $('#img').val(e);
        } else {
            alert('File Failed, Upload File of Size < 1MB');
        }
    } ,
    error: function(e) { alert('error' + e.message); } ,
    // Form data
    data: formData,
    //Options to tell jQuery not to process data or worry about content-type.
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false
});
```

instead of going to else, on response `bad` & `No`. It displays `File Upload Success!` and add image `src` as `bad` and `No`, on different failure.

Am i doing something wrong with If else :-

Response from upload.php are :- `FileName`, `bad` , & `No`.

Thanks

Comment: You should really post the actual response from `upload.php`

Comment: @RGraham the actual response is :- On Success `FileName of Image`, On Failure of no image type `bad` and on size failure `no`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your `||` should be `&&`.

You are saying: if the response is not this OR not that -- that is by definition always true.

Comment: You did it sir, While selecting your answer, got response `Thanks I can accept this answer in 10 minutes`, Y stackoverflow does not allow answer to get accepted immediately ? :-o.I will come back and accept it in 10 minutes. Thanks

Comment: Beat me by a millisecond :)

Comment: [why you can't accept straight away](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47814/why-do-you-have-to-wait-8-minutes-before-you-can-accept-an-answer)

Comment: Welcome @JohnCargo! This is one of those typical errors that you read over again and again... until someone else looks at it :-)

Comment: Interesting link, @Liam! Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

you need `&&`, as you're using or (`||`) above

If `e` is `Bad`, then it is `not No`....if `e` is `No`, then it is `not Bad`...so `No` or `Bad`  will always filter through.

```
if (e != "bad" || e != "No") {
```

should be...

```
if (e != "bad" && e != "No") {
```

Answer (score 0):

*e* is either *No* or *Bad*. Your if statement is always true, because when the *e* is *No* it is obviously not *Bad* and you use or (||) operator. So, you are saying: "take this as true if  *e* is not *No* or it is not *Bad*.

Use:

```
if (e != "bad" && e != "No") {
```